# Db2 select certain columns not working after set Integrity

Tags: database, select, db2

Im learning DB2 and I had a problem while testing some options in my db.

I have 2 tables like this:

```
Country
=========
IdCountry  -- PK
Name

State
=========
IdState  -- PK
IdCountry  -- FK to Country.IdCountry
Name
Code
```

And I am using queries like:

```
SELECT IdState, Name 
FROM Tables.State 
WHERE IdCountry = ?
```

Where ? is any working `IdCountry`, and everything worked fine.

Then I used set integrity in my db2 control center using the default info in the options and the process was successful but now my query isn't giving me any results.

I tried using :

```
SELECT * 
FROM Tables.State 
Where IdCountry = ?
```

and it gives me back results.

While making tests to the table I try adding new States and they appear in the query using column names instead of *, but old records still missing.

I have no clue about what's happening, does anyone have an idea?.

Thanks in advance, and sorry for my poor English.

Comment: For future considerations - don't stick your tables in a schema named `Tables`, give it something a little more descriptive ('exercises', maybe?).  Also, although there's a debate about whether to use the table name in id columns, the usual practice is to use them as _prefixes_, not suffixes (so, `countryId`).  I'm not familiar with the `set integrity` feature, but do you still have your base data - is it possible this was deleted as part of the processes (ie, missing foreign keys)?  As an aside, although many countries have the _equivalent_ of 'state's, not all of them do.

Comment: Sorry about the naming, those are just example names, real tables are actually bigger and with spanish names on it but the idea is the same of those example tables.  

The data still in the table, in fact when i use:  
    SELECT *  
    FROM Tables.State  
    Where IdCountry = 5   

it show the results, but changing * for Column Names doesnt return any.  

Btw thanks for advices and for edit the text, first time posting and it was kinda late for me, didnt have time to check out the posting options u_u

Comment: That feels... bizarre.  Could we get what options you took, and what state it's currently in?  While the statement appears to limit what queries can be run (depending on settings), it doesn't initally appear to limit that columns can't be specified.  Oh, use back-ticks ('`') to format code in comments.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming here that you're on Linux/Unix/Windows DB2, since z/OS doesn't have a `SET INTEGRITY` command, and I couldn't find anything about it with a quick search on the iSeries Info Center.

---

It's *possible* that your table is still in "set integrity pending" state (previously known as `CHECK PENDING`).  You could test this theory by checking [`SYSCAT.TABLES`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0001063.html) using this query:

```
SELECT TRIM(TABSCHEMA) || '.' || TRIM(TABNAME) AS tbl,
       CASE STATUS
            WHEN 'C' THEN 'Integrity Check Pending'
            WHEN 'N' THEN 'Normal'
            WHEN 'X' THEN 'Inoperative'
       END As TblStatus
FROM SYSCAT.TABLES
WHERE TABSCHEMA NOT LIKE 'SYS%'
```

If your table shows up, you will need to use the [`SET INTEGRITY`](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9r7/topic/com.ibm.db2.luw.sql.ref.doc/doc/r0000998.html) command to bring your table into checked status:

```
SET INTEGRITY FOR Tables.State IMMEDIATE CHECKED
```